# Limiting access to some Azure Functions to members of an AD group

Tags: azure-functions

Newly experimenting with Azure Functions from within my client's domain, I've successfully deployed one, and invoked it from a .NET console application.

I'd like to limit access to the function to in-house users that are members of an AD group. I realize that's probably not what functions are meant for, so don't hesitate to express your reservations.

Despite hours spent googling around, all I could achieve was activating AppService Authentication, as described [here](https://peteskelly.com/secure-functions-aad-2/) under section "Configure Authentication and Authorization".

My console application then started failing with code 401 Unauthorized and "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" in the response content - so far so good... I then thought I could just tell Azure to require membership in an AD group to invoke the function, à la WCF, *but how?* I can't manage my client's Azure Active Directory, so maybe I just can't get to where this association can be made (if at all possible).

Here's my code for calling the function:

```
    private static async void CallMyTypedFunctionAsync()
    {
        var functionAddress = "https://[...].azurewebsites.net/api/MyTypedFunction";
        var requestDto = new DataContracts.MyTypedFunctionReqest { X = 6, Y = 7 };

        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, functionAddress)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestDto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var responseDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataContracts.MyTypedFunctionResponse>(responseContent);
            Console.WriteLine("CallMyTypedFunctionAsync's result: {0}", responseDto.Z); // 42
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("CallMyTypedFunctionAsync has failed. {0}: {1}", response.StatusCode, responseContent);
    }
```

Comment: You will have to sync your AD to Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas mentioned that you need to sync your AD to Azure AD directory. 
How to do that you could refer to [Integrate your on-premises directories with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect).

About how to access the Azure Function that protected by Azure AD, please refer to work with Authentication in the Function section in the 
[Azure Functions and App Service Authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2018/02/19/azure-functions-and-app-service-authentication/)